# Websockets - is an "error" event always followed by a "close" event?

Tags: javascript, events, websocket

I'm trying to robustalise the error handling code in a project using Websockets. Currently, our code will catch an "error" event as well as a "close" event and use various heuristics (e.g. has the open event been received yet? have various packets specific to our project been received yet?) to decide what kind of close/error occurred and then immediately unregister event handlers and destroy all references to the Websocket.

I've been looking at using the [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent#Status_codes) instead, but although the close event gives you this, the error event does not - and the error event always seems to be sent first. So if I clean up the Websocket when the first of these events is sent, I'll never receive the status code.

The obvious solution is to ignore the error event and only handle the close event, but this raises a concern: **can the error event ever be fired without a close event being fired immediately after it?** (If it was, the amended code would miss it.) The only relevant part of the spec I can see is [this part](https://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#closeWebSocket), which states that when the connection is closed, step 2 fires an error event and step 3 fires a close event, but I cannot see anything which states that an error event cannot be fired for some other reason.

If an answer can point me to a part of the spec that proves this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are reading the spec correctly - there are no other references to the raising of the `error` event, meaning that the only time you will see the `error` event firing is during the closure of the websocket (if it has errored, not during a "normal" close), and it will always be followed by the `close` event.

Given that during the `close` event you can inspect the event information to find out whether it was cleanly closed or not, one wonders what purpose the `error` event is intended for - it would seem that you only need to worry about handling the `close` event, and looking at the `wasClean` and `reason` properties to determine if it was caused due to an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about this in RFC6455. In the Opening handshake section, it is said among others:

> 4. If the connection could not be opened, either because a direct
>    connection failed or because any proxy used returned an error,
>    then the client MUST *Fail the WebSocket Connection* and abort
>    the connection attempt.

In the [Fail the Websocket Connection](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-7.1.7) section we find (emphasis mine):

> Certain algorithms and specifications require an endpoint to *Fail
> the WebSocket Connection*.  To do so, **the client MUST *Close the
> WebSocket Connection***, and MAY report the problem to the user (which
> would be especially useful for developers) in an appropriate manner.
> Similarly, to do so, the server MUST *Close the WebSocket
> Connection*, and SHOULD log the problem.

This seems to indicate that a `close` event would be fired consistently. However, continuing:

> If *The WebSocket Connection is Established* prior to the point where
> the endpoint is required to *Fail the WebSocket Connection*, the
> endpoint SHOULD send a Close frame with an appropriate status code
> (Section 7.4) before proceeding to *Close the WebSocket Connection*.
> **An endpoint MAY omit sending a Close frame if it believes the other
> side is unlikely to be able to receive and process the Close frame,
> due to the nature of the error that led the WebSocket connection to
> fail in the first place**.  An endpoint MUST NOT continue to attempt to
> process data (including a responding Close frame) from the remote
> endpoint after being instructed to *Fail the WebSocket Connection*.

If the connection was not made (no HTTP upgrade) in the first place, it may not be fired.

To conclude: It is indeed possible that `error` is fired without `close` after it, you can test it on [the datatracker.ietf.org website](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) by opening Dev Tools (F12), and running this in the console:

```js
try
{
    var ws = new WebSocket('wss://blabla');
    ws.onopen = () => console.log('ws open');
    ws.onerror = () => console.log('ws error');
    ws.onclose = () => console.log('ws close');
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log('new WebSocket error (bad url?)');
}
```

It only reports `ws error`, and a message that complains about the Content Security Policy configuration. So no `close` event is fired.

This is slightly annoying for handling automatic reconnection and the like. Especially since you can also not check the `readyState`, which indicates `WebSocket.CLOSED` (`3`) in each case. Any solution would require either a flag to indicate a callback was called already, or in the `error` event handler, you need to remove the callback from the `close` to prevent a double callback.